# How to fix problem with "Uncaught Error: unknown type: dragstart"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js

When I try to drag an element I get the error:

> 'Uncaught Error: unknown type: dragstart'

What does it mean?

````
    const drag = d3
    .drag()
    .on('dragstart', dragstarted)
    .on('drag', dragged)
    .on('dragend', dragended)```
````

````
container
.append('g')
.attr('class', 'dot')
.selectAll('circle')
.append('circle')
.attr('r', 5)
.attr('cx', 30)
.attr('cy', 30)
.call(drag)```
````

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Drag events of d3-drag are `start`, `drag`, `end`. So if you change your code,

```
const drag = d3
.drag()
.on('start', dragstarted)
.on('drag', dragged)
.on('end', dragended)
```

your problem will be resolved.